# Activity animation like google play store

Tags: android, android-animation

I have `GridView` and I want `animation` like google play store. In that, when we click on any app then it redirect to its detail page. At that time a little animation happens. I want this kind of animation for my `GridView` and its detail page. I need help if anyone aware about this kind of activity transition from one class to another class.

Answer (score 6):

**This is your First Activity Code from where you want to move to details screen**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityOptionsCompat;
import android.support.v4.util.Pair;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;

public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        View imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        View textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        View button = findViewById(R.id.button);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EndActivity.class);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            textView.setTransitionName(getString(R.string.activity_text_trans));
            button.setTransitionName(getString(R.string.activity_mixed_trans));

            Pair<View, String> pair1 = Pair.create(imageView, imageView.getTransitionName());
            Pair<View, String> pair2 = Pair.create(textView, textView.getTransitionName());
            Pair<View, String> pair3 = Pair.create(button, button.getTransitionName());
            ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                    makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, pair1, pair2, pair3);
            startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
        }
        else {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the details screen activity**

```
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;

public class EndActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_end);

        View smallImageView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        View editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            smallImageView.setTransitionName(getString(R.string.activity_text_trans));
            editText.setTransitionName(getString(R.string.activity_mixed_trans));
        }
    }

}
```

**FirstActivity layouut file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/aa_logo_green"
        android:transitionName="@string/activity_image_trans"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView"
        android:text="Simple TextView"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Click Me"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EndActivity xml layout file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/aa_logo_green"
        android:transitionName="@string/activity_image_trans"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:hint="An EditText"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/aa_logo_blue"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You want exactly material activity transaction, read this [developer doc here](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html)
also try this lib for **Translation animation** https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations

Comment: This is not a "lib". It's an explanation of how to use google's [Android Transition Framework](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/overview.html). And it's great!